# Expectation of maximum of infinite IID random variables

Tags: probability

Recently I have considered the following question: for a sequence of IID random variables (maybe normal distribution), the expectation of the maximum of $n$ such kind of variables is dependent on $n$, so if $n$ goes to infinity, will the expectation of the maximum of infinite IID random variables be infinite? What is the upper bound of it?

Answer (score 3):

If the support of your distribution is not bounded above (e.g., for a Gaussian distribution), then you will have for every $x$ that there is some $\epsilon > 0$ so that $P(X_j > x) = \epsilon$ for all your i.i.d. variables $X_j$. So the probability that no $X_j$ is greater than $x$ is $(1 - \epsilon)^n$ if you have $n$ variables, which goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Thus by the Markov inequality, your expectation for the maximum must go to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Use Y to denote the maximum. By Markov inequality, E[Y]>=xP(Y>x), first we need n goes to infinity and then x goes to infinity?

Answer (score 1):

To give a bit more background, shamelessly stolen from Chapter $0$ of Resnick's *Extreme Values, Regular Variation, and Point Processes*: let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ denote your i.i.d. random variables from distribution $F$ (say) and write $M_n=\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ for all $n$, then $P(M_n\leq x)=P(\cap_{i=1}^n \{X_i\leq x\})=F^n(x)$ for all real $x$. So the distribution function of $M_n$ is $F^n$.

In consequence, with $x_0=\sup\{x: F(x) < 1\}\leq \infty$, it is true that $M_n\to x_0$ almost surely (because if $x<x_0$, then $P(M_n\leq x)=F^n(x)\to 0$ since $F(x)<1$. So the sequence $(M_n)_n$ converges to $x_0$ in probability. As $(M_n)_n$ is a non-decreasing sequence, convergence in probability implies almost sure convergence). So not only the expectation, but the random variable $M_n$ itself converges (almost surely) to $\infty$ if $x_0=\infty$.

In this sense, things are not interesting. They become interesting if one introduces normalizing sequences $(a_n)>0$ and $(b_n)$ such that $$P((M_n-b_n)/a_n\leq x)=F_n(a_nx+b_n)\to G(x)$$ (weakly) for a non-degenerate $G$. This is one of the starting points in classical [extreme value theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory).

Comment: For continuous random variables with unbounded support, $X_0=\infty$, so the maximum convergences (almost surely) to $\infty$.

Comment: That is true, but as far as I see, (absolute) continuity has no importance. The support matters.